# scala: code optimization: [find an item with max value from the list or return None if equals]

Tags: scala

Trying to optimize next piece of code:

```
private val players = scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.empty[Player]

private def MaxDice(p1: Player, p2: Player): Player = if (p1.LastDice > p2.LastDice) p1 else p2

private def MinDice(p1: Player, p2: Player): Player = if (p1.LastDice < p2.LastDice) p1 else p2

def NextPlayer() : Option[Player] = {
  val maxPlayer = this.players.reduceLeft(MaxDice)
  val minPlayer = this.players.reduceLeft(MinDice)
    if (maxPlayer.LastDice == minPlayer.LastDice) 
      None 
    else 
      Option(maxPlayer)
}
```

is there a way to do this in more sophisticated way?

Comment: In other words, you try to find 2 players, one with smallest `LastDice` value, and one with greatest. Then if those 2 are the same player, you return `None`, otherwise the player with the greatest `LastDice` value. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Apologies for not clear question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to do comparison is other places of the app, you can extract the `Ordering` into `Player`'s companion object:

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.7 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_66-internal).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)


case class Player(lastDice: Int)

object Player {
  implicit val ordering: Ordering[Player] = Ordering.by(_.lastDice)
}

val players = List(Player(2), Player(2))

players.max == players.min

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined class Player
defined object Player
players: List[Player] = List(Player(2), Player(2))
res0: Boolean = true
```

**Addendum:**

Another thing to consider is the size of the list. `max` and `min` will throw exception if list is empty:

```
def min[B >: A](implicit cmp: Ordering[B]): A = {
  if (isEmpty)
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("empty.min")

  reduceLeft((x, y) => if (cmp.lteq(x, y)) x else y)
}

def max[B >: A](implicit cmp: Ordering[B]): A = {
  if (isEmpty)
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("empty.max")

  reduceLeft((x, y) => if (cmp.gteq(x, y)) x else y)
}
```

And if list only contains 1 player, your logic will incorrectly give you `None`. To take all this into account the easiest thing might be working with the sorted list.

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

case class Player(lastDice: Int)

object Player {
  implicit val orderingDescending: Ordering[Player] =
    Ordering.fromLessThan(_.lastDice > _.lastDice)

  def nextPlayer(players: List[Player]): Option[Player] = {
    val sorted = players.sorted
    sorted match {
      case first :: Nil => Some(first)
      case first :: second :: _ if first.lastDice != second.lastDice => Some(first)
      case _ => None
    }
  }
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined class Player
defined object Player

scala> Player.nextPlayer(List[Player]())
res2: Option[Player] = None

scala> Player.nextPlayer(List(Player(1)))
res3: Option[Player] = Some(Player(1))

scala> Player.nextPlayer(List(Player(1), Player(4)))
res5: Option[Player] = Some(Player(4))

scala> Player.nextPlayer(List(Player(1), Player(4), Player(4)))
res6: Option[Player] = None

scala> Player.nextPlayer(List(Player(1), Player(1), Player(4)))
res7: Option[Player] = Some(Player(4))
```

NB: You'll have to change ordering to descending.

Comment: Well, this is more sophisticated. I agree that ordering must be extracted and kept with the original class. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `maxBy` and `minBy` methods:

```
val maxPlayer = this.players.maxBy(_.LastDice)
val minPlayer = this.players.minBy(_.LastDice)
```

Otherwise, there's not much to optimize I think.

Comment: Yes, this will actually do. Thanks, not sure if there is more could be done:                                                                             def NextPlayer() : Option[Player] = this.players.maxBy(_.LastDice) == this.players.minBy(_.LastDice) ? None : Some(this.players.maxBy(_.LastDice)